# Configuration of the application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuration

I am trying setting up application configuration. Problem is that nothing is readed from the configuration. I am using this code:

Sections:

```
public class TownSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    public static TownSection.GetConfig()
    {
        return (TownSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                .GetSection("TownSection") ?? new TownSection();
    }

    [System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty("TownProperties")]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(TownProperties), AddItemName = "TownProperty")]
    public TownProperties TownProperties
    {
        get
        {
            object o = this["TownProperties"];
            return o as TownProperties;
        }
    }        
}
```

List of the entities:

```
public class TownProperties: ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public TownProperty this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BaseGet(index) as TownProperty ;
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }
            this.BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    public new TownProperty this[string responseString]
    {
        get { return (TownProperty)BaseGet(responseString); }
        set
        {
            if (BaseGet(responseString) != null)
            {
                BaseRemoveAt(BaseIndexOf(BaseGet(responseString)));
            }
            BaseAdd(value);
        }
    }

    protected override System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new TownProperty();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((TownProperty)element).Name;
    }

}
```

Entity:

```
   public class TownProperty: ConfigurationElement
   {
    [ConfigurationProperty("Name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this["Name"] as string;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Distance", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Distance
    {
        get
        {
            return this["Distance"] as string;
        }
    }
  }
```

Configuration in app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <sectionGroup name="TownSection">
       <section
             name="TownSection"
             type="App.Configurations.TownSection"
             allowLocation="true"
             allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
     </sectionGroup>
   </configSections>
<TownSection>
  <TownProperties>
     <TownProperty Name="A" Distance="1.8"/>
     <TownProperty Name="B" Distance="5.8"/>
  </TownProperties>
</TownSection>
```

in code:

```
        var config = TownSection.GetConfig();
        foreach(TownProperty item in config.TownProperties) /// cycle is skipped
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Distance);
        }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5681163/1017882 < try that.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed couple of things in xml and that works.

1.Removed Section group tag

2.Added assembly name in `section` tag's type attribute. In format (Full type name, Assembly name)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      <section
            name="TownSection"
            type="App.Configurations.TownSection, App.Configurations"
            allowLocation="true"
            allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
  </configSections>
  <TownSection>
    <TownProperties>
      <TownProperty Name="A" Distance="1.8"/>
      <TownProperty Name="B" Distance="5.8"/>
    </TownProperties>
  </TownSection>
</configuration>
```