# Reading and iterating through xml elements in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am just started working with C# language and looking for a way to iterate though the elements and child elements from a xml file.

My xml Looks like this-

```
  <ServerList>
     <server name = "serverName1" username ="username" password ="password">
      <serviceName>serviceName</serviceName>
      <serviceName>serviceName</serviceName>
      <serviceName>serviceName</serviceName>
   </server>
<server name = "serverName2" username ="username" password = "password">
       <serviceName>serviceName</serviceName>
       <serviceName>serviceName</serviceName>
  </server>
<ServerList>
```

I am just looking for a approach where i can go through the first server elements and its child elements and than the next server elements and its child.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a single LINQ to XML query to iterate through all the child elements & all the attributes of the child elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482567/how-to-write-a-single-linq-to-xml-query-to-iterate-through-all-the-child-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ to XML as a straightforward approach:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("myXmlFile.xml");

var servers = xdoc.Descendants("server"); 
for (var server in servers) 
{
    var children = server.Elements(); 
    for (var child in children)
    {
        // Do what you want with the server and child here
    }
}
```

If there's much more information you need, you might want to consider using XML deserialization. This will allow you to define classes that map to nodes in your XML schema, deserialize the XML into a graph of strongly typed objects that you can then iterate, filter, transform etc. If you do decide on this approach, I would suggest using [YAXLib](https://github.com/sinairv/YAXLib), because the BCL XML serializer kind of sucks.

Comment: This is 100% wrong, it wil return only `children` (`servicename`s) but not `attributes` like (`name`, `username` and `password`)

Comment: @FarhangAmary `server` is an `XElement` object. Please refer to the MSDN documentation on [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find how you can access attributes, children, descendants and other data corresponding to an element in an XML document.

Comment: Yes Asad that's right, i modified your code a bit and i am able to retrieve the attributes as weill

Comment: @FarhangAmary To get the `name` attribute's value for example, you would use `server.Attribute("name").Value`.

Comment: @FarhangAmary I was just explaining how you could access the attributes of the `server` node, which you mentioned in your comment. Regarding "I told your answer is not complete", what exactly is my answer missing?

Comment: @Asad you didn't show how to retrieve the attributes, see your answer before edit.

Comment: @FarhangAmary The code snippet is identical before and after the edit. The attributes can be accessed using the properties available on the `server` object, as I've mentioned before. If your objection is that I didn't explicitly show property access to the attribute values (as opposed to claiming they are not accessible in the inner loop), this is a silly objection. There are any number of operations on the nodes that I could demonstrate to the OP, such as accessing namespace info, adding children, removing nodes, etc. Without having any idea what the OP intends to do, these are all useless.

Comment: @Asad you are justifying your answer, the general idea in your answer is really good I support it and I told what was exactly missed. but please when somebody has a comment on your answer don't try to justify your answer by showing links, instead of it try to correct your answer, if I didn't see the links you mentioned, a long time before then be sure I couldn't show any defect in your answer. and if you were right then be sure you would mention the points I told at the first in the answer

Comment: @FarhangAmary What would you like me to do in order to correct my answer?

Comment: @Asad I have no right on your answer. but I have commenting right, and now it's not important for me at all. I don't like anything, you do whatever satisfying you. good lock.

Answer (score 2):

Descendants is fine, here's a recursive approach anyway

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XElement x = XElement.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
        recursive(x.Elements());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void recursive(IEnumerable<XElement> elements)
    {
        foreach (XElement n in elements)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("--");
            if (n.Descendants().Any())
            {
                recursive(n.Elements());
            }
            else
            {
             Console.WriteLine(n.Value.ToString());// End of node (leaf)
            }
        }
    }

}
```